# HTML & CSS, parent selector?

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that I want to change my `<div>` background-color and my `<h4>` to `red`, either I mouse in a `<div>` or `<h4>`.

[image]

This is my html (without unnecessary classes).

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><div><span class="icon-bubbles3"></span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><h4>News</h4></a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

So I've been trying to apply `h4:hover {color: red}` then I wanted to target also also my `<div>` while hovering `<h4>`, but there is no something like "parent selector" to target my div. So how can i do this? (I don't want to wrap either `<div>` and `<h4>` with `<a>` tag).

Thanks!

Comment: either I mouse in a **`<div>`** or `<h4>` so why not use `div:hover` and `div:hover h4 `?

Comment: Which `<div>` background color? I see 2, one nested in the other.

Comment: Give the parent div a class and use that as the selector

Comment: I want to have changed colors of `<div>` and `<h4>` together, either I hover `<div>` or `<h4>`

Comment: Use jquery and parent() to select the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need a class on your outer-most div in order to be able to directly reference this without also referencing the "inner div":

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <a href="#"><div><span class="icon-bubbles3"></span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><h4>News</h4></a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Then you can call:

```
.mydiv:hover div {
   background-color:red;
}
.mydiv:hover h4 {
   color:red;
}
```